# Migrating from Windows

Tags: laptop, battery

Recently I've decided to migrate from Windows to Linux.
I've been running Ubuntu 19.10 (and 19.04, 18.4 as well), I've also tried Lubuntu 19.04 and none of them was running smooth enough in terms of battery performance.
I'm currently using a laptop with i3 7100u and 8gb of ram.
Could you recommend me a distro that would work smoother on laptops and won't be as  battery demanding as Ubuntu and Lubuntu?
I've also noticed that Linux distros are usually lacking GPU acceleration, and every time i try to watch FHD video on youtube - the CPU load is increasing up to 50%. Is there any Distros that Uses proper GPU acceleration? Please, don't mention "enable GPU acceleration" flag in firefox or chromium, as i already tried this in several distros, like Ubuntu (and flavours) and Monjaro.

Result of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] HD Graphics 620
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: This is not a matter of distro. Install e.g `laptop-mode-tools` to save battery is it is what you mean by "not running smooth".

Comment: @Pilot6 i already have this one installed, but it doesn't seem to help much

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by smoother.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: it doesn't return anything @Pilot6

Comment: and by "smoother" i mean Battery consumption

Comment: That's not possible that the command return nothing. Don't type it, copy and paste.

Comment: oops, my bad. it returned "
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] HD Graphics 620
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915
"

Comment: That means you miss the last `'`.

Comment: GPU accelerations in broiwsers is a long story. So the answer is: there is no distro that it is as power saving as Windows. You can enable acceleration, but that may cause glitches. That's why it is disabled.

Comment: I've also noticed that some distros doesn't have auto-scale feature for FHD screens. Can you advice me one that does support that out of the box? Sorry for dumb questions

Comment: The only flavors or 'distros' that are on-topic for this site are Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu which can be downloaded at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  How they handle FHD varies on desktop + release, eg. older Lubuntu used GTK2 that had no HD support, likewise Xubuntu has only recently moved to GTK3 so support is very new.  Your question esp. with use of 'distros' appears mostly off-topic though to me (ie. not Ubuntu or official flavor related, and thus *SE Unix & Linux* would be a better fit as not Ubuntu only)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know any GNU/Linux distro which will be more battery friendly than Ubuntu. But of course lightweight flavour of Ubuntu- like Xubuntu should consume a bit less power than vanilla Ubuntu. 
You can try tool like **TLP** to improve battery consumption.TLP is a tool that can  help laptop users save battery power. It is highly customizable to fulfil specific user requirements.

**Installation:**- Run this command in Terminal to install TLP-

`sudo apt install tlp linux-tools-generic`

After installation, go to [this](https://pastebin.com/jhBRfbWV) address. Scroll down, copy all the texts from the box **Raw Paste Data.** Then open Terminl & run-

`sudo -i gedit /etc/default/tlp` ("gedit" is the name of default text editor of Ubuntu. If you use other text editor, put it's name in the command instead).

Select all the text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) on the upcoming window and replace it with the text you just copied on your browser (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). Save the file & restart your PC. See if it makes any difference.

You can visit TLP’s [website](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html) to learn about tweaking it’s configuration.

**Additional tips:**

- Make sure that all the necessary drivers required for hardware acceleration is installed on your system-

  `sudo apt install i965-va-driver-shaders va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils gstreamer1.0-vaapi beignet-opencl-icd vainfo`
- Be sure hardware acceleration enabled on Firefox/Chromium. Then install the add-on "h264ify". It'll force YouTube to stream videos encoded with H.264 codec. By default, YouTube streams VP8/VP9 encoded video. However, this can cause problems with less powerful machines because VP8/VP9 is not typically hardware accelerated.
  In contrast, H.264 is commonly hardware accelerated by GPUs, which usually means smoother video playback and reduced CPU usage.
- Use [MPV](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests) for hardware accelarated video playback. MPV is usually a command-line based player so install [SMPlayer](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Asmplayerdev&package=smplayer) after installing MPV to use it normally. Make sure to select "vaapi" for both as video driver and GPU acceleration codec in SMPlayer preferences. Nvidia GPU users should select "vdpau" (instead of vaapi). People who want to use the [post-processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_post-processing) feature should select "vaapi-copy" or "vdpau-copy (for Nvidia)".

**Notes:**

- Make sure MPV is selected as the playback engine in SMPlayer preferences.
- AMD GPUs are supported by both vaapi and vdpau drivers so selecting any of them will be fine.

Comment: I always install `tlp` on my laptops even though they seldomly run on battery.